# Bootstrap not found in Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to use bootstrap but when I got to the page I get

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Home#index
Showing /Users/user/Ruby/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap/responsive'
(in /Users/user/Ruby/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:16)
```

And the trace

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1332549890933188692_2173263620'
```

Here's what I have. my stylesheet

```
*
*= require twitter/bootstrap
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require twitter/bootstrap/responsive
*/
```

And the js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

I've followed all other tutorials/posts on this, but it still won't work for some reason. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

My application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dumpr</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-narrow">
  <div class="masthead">
    <%= render 'layouts/user_header' %>
    <h3 class="muted"><%= link_to "SimpleDevise", root_path %></h3>
    <h5 class="muted">A demo of using SimpleDB with Devise</h5>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your `application.html.erb`.It says it cant find `'twitter/bootstrap/responsive'` file.

Comment: Are you using gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" ?

Comment: Just updated it. @Pavan

Comment: Yes I am using it @ShamsulHaque

Comment: Try commenting this line `*= require twitter/bootstrap/responsive` from your stylesheet.

Comment: I then get `couldn't find file 'bootstrap'` @Pavan

Comment: Just restart your server and check again.

Comment: Now I get `couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'` @Pavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gemfile add the line:-

```
gem "less-rails", '2.2.6'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", '2.2.6'
```

Run this command if you are using less:-

```
rails generate bootstrap:install less
```

If you don't need to customize the stylesheets using Less, then in Gemfile:-

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", '2.2.6'
```

Run this command:-

```
rails generate bootstrap:install static
```

And remove this line from css file:

```
*= require twitter/bootstrap
*= require twitter/bootstrap/responsive
```

For more information see [bootstrap wiki](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)

Answer (score 0):

You should try implementing bootstrap through the bootstrap-sass gem.

Here is the link: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

- Have been using this one for quite some time

Comment: At SO please try to describe whats behind that link, rather then just post it. Since _you're_ answering, instead of doing research for the OP